# Sending emails with mail command

Tags: vps, postfix-mta

I am setting up a VPS with thirtybees and I need to send out confirmation emails,etc...

To send emails, I've been setting up postfix with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

followed by

```
service postfix start
```

and then trying to test it out with

```
echo “test” | mail -s “Test mail “ myemail@gmail.com
```

I receive nothing.

I have a domain pointing out at my VPS IP and the confing in main.cf seems to be alright.

I have tried to follow multiple tutorials over the internet but none has worked so far, some suggesting to modify main.cf domains in different ways, none have worked so far.

Comment: I don't know much but after installing `postfix` you need to set `Select (Mail Configuration)` to `Internet Site` and `System Mail Name (FQDN)` to `DOMAIN.COM` or `NAME OF DROPLET`. This config is enough to send mail from `php`

Comment: do you installed `mailutils` ?

Comment: `sendmail_path=/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

Comment: @Akam  "-bash: -t: command not found"

Comment: @CodeBug Yes, I have.

Comment: @UmairKhan That's exactly the process I have been through, I am desperate at the moment.

Comment: https://devanswers.co/how-to-get-php-mail-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-digitalocean-droplet/ check this

Comment: Take a look at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix and https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/